# Соединение роутов express js и next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, nextjs

Я хочу использовать для серверной части express js в Next js. Но если я пытаюсь отправить запрос на роут который я прописал в express js я получаю ошибку 405. Не могу понять в чем проблема.

Проблема появляется только на хостинге[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код express сервера:

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' //true false
const nextApp = next({ dev })
const handle = nextApp.getRequestHandler() //part of next config

nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const showRoutes = require("./routes");
app.use('/asd', showRoutes) 
app.get('*', (req,res) => {
    return handle(req,res)
})
app.listen(PORT, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`ready at http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})

})
```

routes.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  return res.status(200).json({msg: 'ok'})
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: скорее всего роут ожидает запрос с одним методом, а ты шлешь с другим. Например `POST` вместо `GET` т.д.

Comment: Но все-таки хорошо бы поделиться кодом...

Comment: Я указыввю метод post и отправляю post на mysite.com/api/login

Comment: Проблема появляется при деплое на хостинг

Comment: если проблемы с хостингом - нужно проверить адреса

Comment: С хостингом все хорошо, я использую Vercel

Comment: посмотри логи с хостинга, доходит ли выполнение до твоего кода

Comment: Я приложил картинку с ошибками

Comment: @Antonio либо vercel не поддерживает кастомный сервер, либо вы неверно обрабатываете запросы. Приложите обратчик роутов експресс.

Comment: Я обновил вопрос и добавил в него код

Comment: судя по коду ты должен слать на asd/login и get, а не api/login и post

Comment: Я посылаю get, просто я еще post тестировал

Comment: Но я везде сверял чтобы методы были одиноковыми

Comment: ты посылаешь get и получаешь 405 ответ?

Comment: Уже все понял и написал ответ, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vercel не может использовать кастомный сервер в месте с next js
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13306